# Is a relational database with a dynamic number of tables a good design?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a use case where I wish to create a table for each entity to which the underlying application that owns this entity will publish records.

This table has a fixed structure, so if there are 5 such entities in my system, there will be 5 different tables with the same schema.

The schema is generic with one of the columns in the schema as JSON for flexibility. I do not expect queries based on the fields in the JSON. I expect the following queries on each entity:

1. On the auto-increment id primary key column with LIMIT and OFFSET where I need to read X rows from the record with id Y.
2. On the creation date column with LIMIT X.

I expect thousands of such entities to be created on the fly so in turn there will be thousands of tables in the database.

In future when one of these entities have fulfilled their purpose, the table would be simply deleted.

I expect most of these tables to have not more than 100 rows while there will be a few with at least 1M rows as time goes by.
This design makes data easy to query as my application can determine the table name from the entity name.

Is this a bad design?

Is there a limit to the number of tables in a database in RDBMS (the above design is with Postgresql 11 in mind) keeping performance in mind?

Should I use any different datastore to achieve this other than RDBMS? Any suggestions?

Comment: DDL executed from client code is bad practice. Exclusion - database version upgrade utility.

Comment: Don't do this. See [What's worse, too many entities or too many tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88767/whats-worse-too-many-entities-or-too-many-tables)

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of tables in a database in RDBMS? There is always a limit regardless if you choose Postgres, any other RDBMS or any other database. You are unlikely to hit that limit though. A typical SAP installation contains roughly 100000 tables (I've heard). That said, I would rethink the design. Letting the application manipulate the model is most of the time if not always, a bad idea.

Comment: I would like to understand what business problem you are trying to solve. What is an ENTITY ? What does it represent ? Is it that you want to implement a kind of “multi-tenant” environment, allowing multiple customers to store private data in isolation from others ?

Comment: Also are all entities using the exact same table structure ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bad design?

Yes.  See comment by LowlyDBA.

> Is there a limit to the number of tables in a database in RDBMS ...

Each RDBMS has a different maximum number of tables.  There is a Q&A for this is on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395883/postgresql-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-tables-can-store-in-postgresql-databas).

> Should I use any different datastore to achieve this other than RDBMS?

No. RDBMS should be fine if you design your schema correctly.

> Any suggestions?

From your description, a single table with `Entity_Name` as part of the Primary Key should work. A table with 100M rows is not a problem for today's databases.

```sql
create table data_for_entity (
  entity_name     varchar(50),
  entity_id       int,
  entity_value    text, -- or whatever PostgreSQL uses for JSON
  constraint data_for_entity_pk Primary Key (entity_name, entity_id)
);
```

Comment: Recommending that people stuff everything into a JSON is bad advice.

Comment: But the OP says he wants a JSON column. His question is not about whether he should use JSON or not. This answer just uses the information given by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your tables have the same columns, you could simply have

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
   entity_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   entity_name text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   /* other descriptive attributes */
);

CREATE TABLE data (
   data_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   entity_id bigint REFERENCES entity NOT NULL,
   col1 ...,
   col2 ...,
   ...
);

CREATE INDEX ON data (entity_id);
```

Then rather than using a special table for an entity, you simply add a join with `entity` to all your queries. That will perform well.

Besides making your code more complicated (you could not use prepared statements!), using many tables can also be a maintenance and performance problem.

The metadata tables and metadata queries in PostgreSQL are not laid out for big data, so if you have tens of thousands of tables, there might be slowdowns in unexpected places.

Answer (score -1):

Your requirements seem to fit an OS's file system more than a RDBMS.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156941)

Comment: My answer is not a critique. My response answers the question "Is this a bad design" by pointing out that a OS file system meets the requirements.